# I would like to seperate value and key from array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, laravel

I would like to get value of the id and the parent_id from this array(PHP Laravel) to update the database.

```
stdClass Object( [item_id] => [parent_id] => [depth] => 0 [left] => 1 [right] => 12)
stdClass Object( [id] => 1 [parent_id] => [depth] => 0 [left] => 2 [right] => 3)
stdClass Object( [id] => 2 [parent_id] => [depth] => 0 [left] => 4 [right] => 5)
stdClass Object( [id] => 4 [parent_id] => [depth] => 0 [left] => 6 [right] => 7)
stdClass Object( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => [depth] => 0 [left] => 8 [right] => 11)
stdClass Object( [id] => 6 [parent_id] => 5 [depth] => 1 [left] => 9 [right] => 10)
```

**controller :**

```
public function updatemenusort(Request $request)
{
     $menus=json_decode($request->input('menu'));

     foreach($menus as $menu)
     {
        print_r($menu);
     }
}
```

**ajax from view:**

```
$('#toArray').click(function (e) {
    arraied = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray', {startDepthCount: 0});
    //arraied = dump(arraied);
    arraied = JSON.stringify(arraied);
    // ajax strt

    alert(arraied);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{url('menus/sortmenu')}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'menu': arraied, '_token': _token},
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (data) {}
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use [this](http://ilikenwf.github.io/example.html) plugin to create a drag-able and sort-able menu.
The above array is the output of `(print_r($menu);)` from my controller.

Comment: @ThomasMoors Its just as easy to foreach over an object

Comment: @ThomasMoors except in this case the OP has no use for `$menu_key`

Answer (score 0):

You have itereated over the array of objects so now you have `$menu` set to a single object instance.

So simply access the data as an object and its properties.

```
public function updatemenusort(Request $request)
{
     $menus=json_decode($request->input('menu'));

     foreach($menus as $menu)
     {
        echo $menu->id;
        if ( isset($menu->parent_id) {
            echo $menu->parent_id;
        } else {
            echo 'No parent Id';
        }
        // etc etc

        // In your case I assume you would want to
        // build a query here and not just echo data,
        // but thats just a FLOC
     }
}
```

Comment: i did. but error..(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
public function updatemenusort(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->menu as $menu)
    {
        // if you are finding by id 

        $model = ModelName::find($menu['id']); // can use findOrFail()

        // checking if not null 
        if (!is_null($model)) { // remove if using findOrFail()
            $model->id = $menu['id'];
            $model->parent_id = $menu['parent_id'];
            $model->save();
        }

        /*---------------------or---------------------*/

        // creating new but here you might get duplicate id error 

        $model = new ModelName;
        $model->id = $menu['id'];
        $model->parent_id = $menu['parent_id'];
        $model->save();

    }
}
```

**Previous Suggestions this is not relevant to above**

You can use `array_column()` for this. if you want `id` and `parent_id` in new array.

**For Example**

```
$ids = array_column($menus, 'id'); // for id
$parentId = array_column($menus, 'parent_id'); // for parent id
```

**Suggestion**

I have no idea why you are using `arraied = JSON.stringify(arraied);` just pass object as it is and in **controller**

```
//$menus=json_decode($request->input('menu')); // no need to use json_decode() if you are doing to get as object then you can do like 

$menus= $request->input('menu');

foreach($menus as $menu)
{
    $menu = (object) $menu; // you can cast here
    print_r($menu);
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gnc2j4 https://prnt.sc/gnc20k  https://prnt.sc/gnc2bv https://prnt.sc/gnc344 http://prntscr.com/gnc2wq .I did as you told but i didn't get you completely please check screen shorts i am a beginner

Comment: why you are `alerting` object, if you want to see result then you can use `console.log(arraied)`

Comment: You want `id` and `parent_id` in one array like `["id" => 6, "parent_id" => 5]`  or separately like `$ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `$parentIds = [5]` ;

Comment: it is very simple updating answer.